# Not able to load the saved graph using torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter.add_graph method

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I am saving the scalar summary along with model graph using  `add_scalar` and `add_graph` methods from `torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter`.

While running tensorboard on the summary file, it doesnt show the model graph. Just 2 small rectangle at the bottom right, However, it is able to show the scalar variable and images.

Sample code from the pytorch documentation attached

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

# Writer will output to ./runs/ directory by default
writer = SummaryWriter()

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
trainset = datasets.MNIST('mnist_train', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(False)

print(model)

# Have ResNet model take in grayscale rather than RGB
model.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))

grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(images)
writer.add_image('images', grid, 0)
writer.add_graph(model, images)
writer.close()
```

Any pointer to the solution would be appreciated

> PyTorch version - 1.2.0 Tensorboard version - 1.15.0a20190828

[image: Attaching the bottom right crop of the tensorboard]

Comment: Double click on those two rectangles.

Comment: Nothing happens with double click on the rectangles

Comment: Can you share the picture?

Comment: Have attached in the original post

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
Check out this thread:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24157

TLDR: Update PyTorch to PyTorch-nightly and the problem should be solved.
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/